# Looping through data with Parent-Child relationship in Parse

Tags: php, parse-platform

I have 2 tables (classes) in my Parse database, the first is for "Categories" and the other is for "Sub Categories".

Each object in "Sub Categories" has a field that holds it's master's Object-ID inside the "Categories" table.

My question is, how do I go about looping through them?
Lets say I want to get all of the data in "Categories" while retrieving their related "Sub Categories".

What I am currently doing is, I'm looping for "Categories" and inside this loop I am looping for related "Sub Categories". But somehow it seems wrong to do so (even though it works magically):

```
<?php
// Parse query objects for "Categories"
$categories = new ParseQuery("categories");
$results = $categories->find();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
    $category = $results[$i];
    echo '<option value="' . $category->getObjectId() . '">' . $category->get("cat_name") . '</option>'; // Printing from "Categories"

    // Parse query objects for "Sub Categories"
    $subCategories = new ParseQuery("sub_categories");
    $subCategories->equalTo("master_id", $category->getObjectId());
    $resultsSub = $subCategories->find();

    if ($resultsSub != 0) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($resultsSub); $j++) {
            $subCategory = $resultsSub[$j];
            echo '<option value="' . $subCategory->getObjectId() . '">+ ' . $subCategory->get("cat_name") . '</option>'; // Printing from "Sub Categories"
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner queries by using the matchesQuery option. Have the criteria for parent Category in the inner query and use that with the matchesQuery for the outer query which will be for Sub categories.
https://www.parse.com/docs/php/guide#queries-relational-queries

Additionally in the Sub Category query use the include option to get the parent Category object. This will make sure that every sub category object in the resulting find operation will have its parent Category object.

Hope that helps.